# How can I create a private method inside a plugin?

Tags: jquery

I would like to know if it is possible to create a jQuery private method inside the method like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPublicFunc = function() { 
        $.fn.myPrivateFunc = function() {    
            return this;
        };

        $("a").myPrivateFunc();

        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

or is there another way to join my normal private functions like:

```
var myPrivateFunc = function() {
}
```

into jQuery chain. Sorry for my vocabulary, I hope you will understand my point.

Comment: Should the private function/method be available to the rest of your plugin, or only to the `myPublicFunc` method?

Comment: You cannot expect to encapsulate some method then use it as publicly available plugin (`$('a').myPrivateFunc()`). What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of places you can create private functions:

1. One copy for the plugin *as a whole*
2. A copy per jQuery object using the plugin

I recommend #1. Here's how you do that:

```
function($) {
    $.fn.myPublicFunc = function() { 

        myPrivateFunc($("a"));

        return this;
    };

    function myPrivateFunc($set) {
        // Stuff using `$set` here, for instance
        $set.css("color", "green");
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Note where the private function is created: In the scoping function you wrapped around your plugin's code. Only one copy of the function is created, and then you pass it the jQuery set to work with.

There, `$set` is the jQuery set (object) that `myPrivateFunc` should operate on.

If you prefer to use `this` instead, you use `Function#call` to call it:

```
function($) {
    $.fn.myPublicFunc = function() { 

        myPrivateFunc.call($("a"));

        return this;
    };

    function myPrivateFunc() {
        // Stuff using `this` here, for instance
        this.css("color", "green");
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Note that `this` is the jQuery set, not a DOM element as it is in event callbacks.

Comment: Someone should be rewarded! :D

Answer (score 0):

In order for a method to be chain-able, it must *necessarily* be public, and so not as a method on an object. In JavaScript, scope is set at the function level, and so `myPrivateFunction` would be visible only to the `$.fn.myPublicFunc` method.

You can define a function as you normally would, within the scope of the `$.fn` method, and it'll work just fine:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPublicFunc = function() { 
        var myPrivateFunction = function(elem) {
            return elem;
        };

        myPrivateFunction($("a"));

        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

---

JavaScript functions *can* have their context overriden, and so your initial goal of having `myPrivateFunction` take no arguments could work, using either JavaScript's native [`Function.[call/apply/bind]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) methods, or using jQuery's [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) approach. Here's an example of how that would work with the native `Function.call()`.

```
var myPrivateFunction = function() {
    return this;
};

myPrivateFunction.call($("a"));
```

One drawback of this, is that the context in which `myPrivateFunction` is *supposed* to be invoked is not clear (without necessary documentation), and so JSHint and other JS linters will complain if your modules are adhering to [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) rules.